# SQL Server 2005 Clustered Index Drop running long with no non-clustered indexes present

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, clustered-index

I'm dropping a clustered index from a table in a SQL Server 2005 database and it's taking a very long time to run.

I did some research and determined that dropping a clustered index can take a long time because it's updating pointers in non-clustered indexes to instead reference the RowID of the table itself, however in this particular scenario there are no non-clustered indexes present on the table.

There are a lot of foreign keys in the database, so it's possible that one of them might be referencing the clustered index ID.

Is there any way to determine what objects are using clustered index references as opposed to RowID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a clustered index, everything uses that instead of a `RowID` - the clustered index key **IS** the row identifier.

So the answer is, anything that references that table.

Comment: Is there any way to get a list of those objects?

Comment: @David - you can look at `sys.sysdepends` to check on dependencies.

Comment: I looked on sysdepends and there is one reference to the table with the clustered index in question from a stored procedure.

Comment: @David - you can also take a look at `sp_who2 active` to make sure nothing is blocking you.  If it's a big table it may just take a long time.  How big is it?

Comment: I'm doing this on a development box, so there are no other active users. I'll end up deploying this to production eventually after I'm satisfied with the script and go through some more testing. The overall table size is 246GB in Dev and 600 in Prod (The development environment only contains a sample of the production data)

Answer (score 0):

An easy, visual way to see your foreign key constraints is to add the tables into a Diagram. Then you can see the relationships and check if any are pointing to the clustered index.

However, what is the reason that you are dropping the clustered index, which is most likely the primary key?

Comment: The table is partitioned and the clustered index was not created on the partition, so I need to re-design the index. Because the table in question is very large, I'm trying to determine if there is any simple way to speed up the operation.